# Set label text using JavaScript on a .aspx page

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have put this JavaScript code in file JavaScript.js:

```
var target = Number(prompt("Enter The New Number"));
function monthName(){
    var month = target == 1 ? month = "January" : target == 2 ? month = "February" : target == 3 ? month = "March" : target == 4 ? "April" : target == 5 ? "May" : target == 6 ? "June" : target == 7 ? "July" : target == 8 ? "August" : target == 9 ? "September" : target == 10 ? "October" : target == 11 ? "November" : target == 12 ? "December" : "Unknown Month";
    return month;
}
document.getElementById('yes').html= monthName();
```

And added a label with this particular id.

```
<label id="yes" ></label>
```

Comment: there is no html, there is innerHTML. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Comment: Your ternary is evaluating like `var month = month = "January"`, etc...

Comment: @epascarello i tried innerHTML , InnerText, TextContent also but nothing happened.

Comment: Please search first: [`javascript dom element set content`](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+dom+element+set+content&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)

Comment: Well what is the error in your console. My guess is you have an error that is undefined or null.

Comment: @RajanMishra Where did you place this script? Ensure that you are running the script after the target element has loaded.

Comment: Something certainly happens: https://jsfiddle.net/8kxfLn6r/ .

Comment: @jonuleis yeah but its doing good.

Comment: Side note: Don't nest the conditional operator like that. It can make the code difficult to read. You can just use an array of names here.

Comment: @epascarello yeah id value resulting null

Comment: @felixkling okay i'll fix it. thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @epascarello, use `.innerHTML` instead of `.html`.

> The `Element.innerHTML` property sets or gets the HTML syntax describing the element's descendants.

*Read up*: [`Element.innerHTML` - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

**Working snippet:**

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

  var target = Number(prompt("Enter The New Number"));

  function monthName() {
    var month = target == 1 ? month = "January" : target == 2 ? month = "February" : target == 3 ? month = "March" : target == 4 ? "April" : target == 5 ? "May" : target == 6 ? "June" : target == 7 ? "July" : target == 8 ? "August" : target == 9 ? "September" : target == 10 ? "October" : target == 11 ? "November" : target == 12 ? "December" : "Unknown Month";
    return month;
  }

  document.getElementById('yes').innerHTML = monthName();

});
```

```html
<label id="yes"></label>
```

In response to your comment, add your existing JavaScript code in the event listener of `DOMContentLoaded` with the fix of `.innerHTML`, just to make sure that it is executed after DOM content is loaded. Make sure that you use @mplungjan's JavaScript code inside of the `DOMContentLoaded` event handler since it is well written and better than mine.

Comment: already tried it.

Comment: @RajanMishra But this demo works - did you try it? Though I'd still replace the unnecessary `month = "January"`, etc with just `"January"`.

Comment: @RajanMishra Please elaborate on what the problem is after using my code. Any error in the JS console? Any other unexpected behavior?

Comment: the value returned by the function which is assigned to that dom element is not getting accessed because id is listing as null.

Comment: This code works, but is using a lot of side effects to do so.

Comment: @RajanMishra Please check the EDIT in my updated answer above.

Comment: @mplungjan Yep, I'd clean up the ternary mess as you did already.

Comment: @RahulDesai yeah thanks that really worked.

Comment: @RajanMishra Glad to hear that. Make sure that you use @mplungjan's JS code inside of the `DOMContentLoaded` event handler since it is well written and better than mine.

Comment: @rahuldesai pretty sure i'il mind that.

Comment: @RajanMishra why the un-accept of my answer?

Answer (score 3):

1. input check the number
2. use an array if acceptable input
3. assign to innerHTML (case sensitive)
4. function can only run AFTER the label exists in the DOM
5. note for the future that JS months are 0 based (not relevant here)

```js
function monthName(month) {
  month = month.trim();
  if (isNaN(month) || month == "" || month < 0 || month > 12) return "unknown";
  return ["unknown", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"][month];
}
// this needs to be after the label exists or wrapped in 
// window.onload=function() {...} or similar 
document.getElementById('yes').innerHTML = monthName(prompt("Enter The New Number", ""));
```

```html
<label id="yes"></label>
```

Comment: I'd also add the condition of `month < 0` since you do have `month > 12`.